# what does "-o" mean in font awesome class names?

Tags: css, font-awesome, font-awesome-4

For example, how are the classes "fa-square-o" and "fa-square" different from each other? Where can I find more information on font-awesome class name conventions? I searched on their website, but couldn't find specific guidance on font-awesome class naming conventions.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It means outlined. Some icons have full solid backgrounds, and some others are just outlined, and are named with an extra `-o` at the end of their names. Besides this, there'a also `-alt`, which is used for icons which are alternatives to other icons. E.g., the icon `fa-arrows`, has an alternative `fa-arrows-alt` which has a slight rotation, different from the normal icon. I guess these two are the only ones to be mentioned.

Comment: Could you please provide a link, if you know of one, to the part of the documentation on Font Awesome's website where it explains this.

Comment: @user2407334 I don't have any, because even I didn't read it anywhere. It's just obvious.

Answer (score 6):

> **From Font-Awesome Developer Dave Gandy**

[image]